# React js/ Response 304 status at the log

Tags: reactjs, server, http-status-code-304

I got those error in my react js project server, by the way in the local i have no error everythink working fine, but in the server there is a empty page displayed after click in button, and when i see the log there is those errors:

Error: Unable to find the file /var/www/vhosts/domaine-name/favicon.ico at the specified location

Error: Unable to find the file /var/www/vhosts/domaine-name/13.bafd1c44.chunk.css at the specified location

Error: Unable to find the file /var/www/vhosts/domaine-name/13.ee74bfdf.chunk.js at the specified location

Answer (score 1):

A status code of 304 means that the response is not modified. Essentially, it means that the resource hasn't changed since the last time you requested it.

So say for example you request an endpoint twice, if the second time you request it you get a 304 status code, that means that both the first and the second response are the same and therefore it doesn't need updating.

Usually browsers will attempt to cache information to speed up page delivery, and if the browser receives a 304 status code instead of requesting the resource again it will just serve the cached version of this information.